# Выход из вложенных циклов

Tags: c#

Как выйти из цикла, нужно чтобы условие выполнилось один раз:

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
{
  foreach (DataRow row2 in ds.Tables[3].Rows)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2["nVIN"].ToString()) )
    {
      //условие if(...)
      {
       ...
       break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: из одного break, а из двух развечто 1)return. 2)Результат условия можно присвоить в bool переменную, 3) goto.

Comment: @nick_n_a, через bool попробывал все равно не получается, через goto как ?

Comment: Можно ещё исключение кинуть и обработать его ниже циклов. Однако самый правильный вариант, имхо, выделить в отдельную функцию и сделать `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ 1

```
bool is_break = false;
foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
{
  foreach (DataRow row2 in ds.Tables[3].Rows)
  {
    if (is_break=(String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2["nVIN"].ToString()) ))
// для с++:  if ((is_break=(String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2["nVIN"].ToString()) ))==true)

    {
      //условие if(...)
      {
       ...
       break;
      }
    }

  }
if (is_break) break; /*В уровень первого цикла*/
}
```

Способ 2

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
{
  foreach (DataRow row2 in ds.Tables[3].Rows)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2["nVIN"].ToString()) )
    {
      //условие if(...)
      {
       ...
       goto   exit_label;
       //break;
      }
    }
  }
}
exit_label: // c# не очень любит goto может выдавать warning
```

Comment: `==true` -то зачем? лишнее это сравнение

Comment: @ 3per, да в условии не понадобилось is_break =..true

Comment: Я на всякий случай, что б компилято не ругался на "возможное присваивание" в if, с++ даёт warning, c# не знаю, возможно тоже *warn:posibility incorrect assign*.

Comment: Не подумал об этом, действительно может так и лучше тогда. А вот `if (is_break) break;` во втором способе лишнее, как и вообще флаг

Comment: @3per поправил)