# Как в c# выйти из двойного цикла?

Tags: c#, циклы

Есть двойной цикл `for`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
   {
       if (....)
       {
           ....
       }
       else
       {
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

Из второго цикла я выхожу, но как потом сразу выйти из первого цикла ?

Comment: Что эти циклы делают? Скорей всего вы изначально неправильно написали код, если возникает такая проблема.

Comment: [goto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выход из вложенных циклов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559730/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Grundy: Я бы наоборот тот вопрос сделал дубликатом этого. Этот более общий.

Comment: @VladD, честно говоря не вижу особой разницы. Но ты ж можешь бамкнуть в любую сторону

Comment: @Grundy: Могу, но with great power comes great responsibility :) Поэтому я и переспрашиваю. Этот вопрос о циклах вообще, а тот — о каких-то непонятных условиях на DataRow.

Comment: @VladD, тогда давай наоборот :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Готово!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Для выхода из вложенных циклов со сложной структурой может применяться [оператор goto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/13940fs2.aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
   {
       if (....)
       {
           ....
       }
       else
       {
           goto LoopEnd;
       }
   }
}

LoopEnd: ...
```

---

Альтернативным решением может стать помещение основного цикла в функцию, и применение оператора `return`

```
public void Loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
       {
           if (....)
           {
               ....
           }
           else
           {
               return;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать дополнительный флаг:

```cs
var flag = true;
for(int i=0; flag && i<10; i++)
{
   for (int l=0; flag && l<20; l++)
   {
       if (....)
       {
           ....
       }
       else
       {
          flag = false;
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: хороший вариант (хотя во вложенном цикле **flag** можно не использовать). можно еще использовать оператор **goto** вместо **break**. многие гуру не рекомендуют использовать оператор **goto**, но индусы из Microsoft его част применяют :)

Comment: @Igor: По поводу goto к индусам прибавьте ещё Дональда Кнута

Comment: @VladD, это не показатель того, что необходимо грубейшим образом нарушать структурный подход. Была же уже где-то похожая дискуссия в комментариях, только относительно Java.

Comment: @Arhad, так и про нарушение структурного подхода здесь ни слова нет :)

Comment: @Arhad: Не вижу тут грубейшего нарушения. Избегание goto — не догма; там, где оно уместно, там вполне можно и даже нужно его применять. Посмотрите, насколько тяжеловеснее получается конструкция с флагом!

Comment: @Grundy,  `goto` — это уже само по себе противоречие вышеуказанному подходу. @VladD, `goto` плох тем, что способен «пролететь» всю иерархическую структуру программы и приземлиться в произвольном месте. Как результат, весьма усложняется отладка. `Посмотрите, насколько тяжеловеснее получается конструкция с флагом!` — мы *уже видели* (выше по коду), где этот флаг используется. А метку надо ещё умудриться найти; плюс удержать в голове всю пропущенную этим прыжком логику.

Comment: @Arhad, как минимум в C# его сильно обрезали, поэтому _«пролететь» всю иерархическую структуру программы и приземлиться в произвольном месте_ - весьма проблематично.

Comment: @Arhad, goto считается плохим не потому, что он плохой, а потому, что его неправильно применяют. Человек, который разбирается почему его не используют и когда его использование оправдано, неправильных подходов не применяют. Да даже уже на википедии добавили раздел "common usage patterns of Goto" с описанием оправданного применения и одно из них "выход из глубоких вложенных циклов для повышения читабельности".

Comment: @Arhad: Ну я сошлюсь на мнение экспертов: у Кнута есть знаменитая статья «Структурное программирование с goto». Если уж он не считает, что с goto структурное программирование не сочетается, то и нам не следует.

Comment: @Arhad: Да, с goto _можно_ писать плохой код. Поэтому за использованием goto следует внимательно следить. Но в **данном** случае использование goto, как мне кажется, вполне уместно.

Comment: В принципе, вместо использования `flag` можно просто присвоить переменной внешнего цикла граничное значение `i = 10;` перед `break` во внутреннем цикле, но `goto` в таком коде более очевидное (и поэтому красивое) и краткое решение.

Comment: Манипуляции со счетчиками цикла вне заголовка цикла, имхо, зло похлеще `goto`

Answer (score 4):

Еще один вариант:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
    {
        if (false)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(":)");
        }
        else
        {
            i = Int32.MaxValue - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```